# How to use wp-query to search for posts where post_content OR post_title OR post_name

Tags: wp-query, wpdb

Hi I'm using WP query in WP 6.1.1 like this:

```
    $posts_where = [
        'post_type'      => 'page',
        'posts_per_page' => - 1,
    ];
```

If there are search and status inputs I use those:

```
    $posts_where['s'] = $search;
    $posts_where['post_status'] = $status;
```

And I add in meta queries based on input too if they exist, this isn't super relevant but it's complicated to write in MySQL so it's why I am not just writing it out:

```
$posts_where['meta_query'][] = [
     'key'     => 'content_variations',
     'value'   => '%',
     'compare' => 'LIKE',
];
```

Then I query like this:

```
$posts_query = new \WP_Query($posts_where);
$posts       = $posts_query->posts;
```

I want to change the search so that it will get posts where the value of $SEARCH can also match on post_name as well as title and content. I can see that the query that S makes is:

```
AND (((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%[SEARCH]%') OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%[SEARCH]%'))
```

is there a way in WP query (i.e. not just writing out the query) to add  `OR (wp_posts.post_name LIKE '%[SEARCH]%')` to that?

UPDATE

I added 'search_columns' to the array along with 's' like this:

```
$posts_where['s'] = $value;
$posts_where['search_columns'] = [
    'post_content',
    'post_name',
    'post_title',
];
```

but I still get the same query:

```
SELECT   wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1  AND (((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '{[long string]}SEARCH{[long string]}') OR (wp_posts.post_excerpt LIKE '{[long string]}SEARCH{[long string]}') OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '{[long string]}SEARCH{[long string]}')))  AND ((wp_posts.post_type = 'page' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'future' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'draft' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'pending' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private'))) ORDER BY wp_posts.post_title LIKE '{[long string]}SEARCH{[long string]}' DESC, wp_posts.post_date DESC
```

Comment: aside from the post name, the inclusion of the `meta_query` forces it to only search those posts that meet that post meta condition. Note that the `meta_query` clause you added can get very expensive/slow.

Comment: That's not a problem. I know meta_query will narrow it down and can be expensive, but I just want to search for post_title as well as the default search columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In WordPress 6.2+, within `WP_Query` you can set `search_columns` parameter (not documented at time of writing) to specify the fields to search:

```php
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    's'              => 'search term',
    'search_columns' => array( 'post_content', 'post_name', 'post_title' ),
) );
```

You can also use [the `post_search_columns` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_search_columns/) to adjust the search columns. You may need to use [the `wp_query_search_exclusion_prefix` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_query_search_exclusion_prefix/) to change the operator. See the definition for [`WP_Query::parse_search()`](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/6.2/src/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php#L1385) for more info.

For WordPress before 6.2, you're likely limited to using [the `posts_where` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/posts_where/).

Comment: Oooh lala! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. ‍♂️

Comment: I added the search column and didn't see it and if I look at the $posts_query->request it's unchanged. How exactly to I use the wp_query_search_exclusion_prefix? I tried giving it different values to no effect.

Comment: Can you please update your question with an **Update** section to show your adjusted query?

Comment: Added, the query is not different at all, other than the different long random strings placed around the search terms.

Comment: I'm using wp 6.1.1 is it an extremely new feature?

Comment: Looks like the filter was introduced in 6.2. Possible the parameter was also. My test was on 6.2.

Comment: Yeah it's too bad your solution seems like it would have been the best.

Comment: Upgrading isn't an option?

Comment: Confirmed that `search_columns` parameter is not available in 6.1.1. Edited my answer for a possible solution before 6.2.

Comment: Created a ticket with documentation team to hopefully get it added: https://github.com/WordPress/Documentation-Issue-Tracker/issues/1384